# a Cufon problem on a nested menu

Tags: list, nested, cufon

I'm building a nested navigation bar, here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8vB/1/

the nested menus are on the third item, "Collezioni": so far so good. But adding Cufon triggers a strange problem: "hovering" the nested menus and going away from them all the way down, the "Collezioni" link disappears!

http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8vB/2/

Well, it doesn't really disappear: it retains the #fff color (:hover) instead of going back to #111 (normal state), and since the background is white too, it "disappears". Going all the way UP (without "hovering" the nested menus) has no problem.

I'm sure it's a Cufon related problem since the first version (without Cufon) is working nice.

Please, can you help to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution here:

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-10

And here's the new jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8vB/3/